# Swift - set delegate for singleton

Tags: ios, swift, singleton

I have something like this:

```
class SocketManager {
    static let instance: SocketManager
    var socket = Socket()
}

extension SocketManager: SocketDelegate {
    func someFunc() {
    }
}
```

`Socket` is a class that has it own `protocol` and `delegate`

```
protocol SocketDelegate: class {
    func someFunc()
}

class Socket {
    weak var delegate: SocketDelegate?
}
```

How can I set `socket.delegate` to `SocketManager.instance`?

Answer (score 2):

You set another class to conform to the `SocketDelegate` protocol and to set the delegate to that class. Once you do that, the `SocketDelegate` can call delegate methods which will be passed to the class that you set the delegate as.

Your classes will be like this:

```
class SocketManager {
    static let instance: SocketManager
    var socket = Socket()
    weak var delegate: SocketDelegate?
}

extension SocketManager: SocketDelegate {
    func someFunc() {
    }
}

protocol SocketDelegate: class {
    func someFunc()
}

class Socket: SocketDelegate { // so it conforms to the delegate
    SocketManager.instance.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: That's what I've done before, however, I'm trying to make my code cleaner by moving them all inside a `Manager` class and `delegate` to outside.

Comment: @PhamHoan the delegate variable goes inside the `Manager` class and you set the `manager.delegate = self` inside `Socket` class :-)