# How to move data in VC using Delegates?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I move the data stored in `data` into the next VC and append it in my list when the `sendDate` is tapped ? Here is my code of the sending class :

```
protocol DataSentDelegate{
     func userDidEnterData(data: String)
}
class SecondViewController: UIViewController{

var delegate: DataSentDelegate!

@IBAction func addItem(_ sender: Any)
{
    let data = textField.text
    delegate?.userDidEnterData(data: data)
}
```

Here is the code of recieving class :

```
class SecondPageViewController: UIViewController, DataSentDelegate{

func userDidEnterData(data: String) {

}

@IBAction func sendDate(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {

}
```

How do I implement `list.append(data!)` where `data` holds the value of `textField.text`

Comment: with your current setup, you are passing data from `SecondViewController` to `SecondPageViewController`.  So inside `func userDidEnterData(data: String)` in your `SecondPageViewController` is where you append the list.

Comment: I want my list only to append when I tap the `sendDate` which is an `IBAction`

Comment: in `SecondPageViewController`, implement `let secondVC = SecondViewController()` just below the line `class`, then inside your `sendData`, implement `secondVC.addItem()`.  Here is a link to help you understand passing data between `ViewControllers`. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guSYMPaXLaw

Comment: Why don't you save the data that receives on userDidEnterData in a local var and then use it in sendDate?

Answer (score 1):

Do you not have to set the delegate in SecondPageViewController to self (normally in ViewDidLoad?

You declared it but don't seem to have assigned it.

Answer (score 1):

You can share data through whole project using Singleton Pattern.

A singleton class is initialised for only once.

Look at these answers:

[Swift - set delegate for singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29536080/swift-set-delegate-for-singleton)

Answer (score 0):

What about you just add an array variable in your `SecondPageViewController` which will hold a list of strings, then append a new string each time `sendDate` delegate method gets called?

A few other remarks, there is no need to declare your delegate var as implicitly unwrapped if you're using optional chaining anyway, just declare it as an optional. Secondly, because `SecondPageViewController` is a class, it's better to make your delegate protocol class bound as such: `protocol DataSentDelegate: class { func userDidEnterData(data: String) }`, thirdly to avoid possible strong reference cycles make your delegate var a weak one.